# Set background color of layout

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets, qlayout

As the layout object has no attribute ".setStyleSheet()", how can one set the background color for a given layout?

As a visual explanation, I can set both the label and the button background color, but not the entire layout, which includes the spacer.

[image]

Programatically, I'm organizing some information in horizontal layouts and displaying them in a frame.  I would like to alternate background colors for each loop.

```
for param_name in parameters:
    hlayouts.append(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
    labels.append(QtGui.QLabel("%s"%param_name))
    sliders.append(QtGui.QSpacerItem(10,10,hPolicy=QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
    spins.append(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox())

    spins[index].setValue(float(values.get(param_name)))
    labels[index].setStyleSheet("background-color:black;")
    spins[index].setStyleSheet("background-color:black;")

    hlayouts[index].addWidget(labels[index])
    hlayouts[index].addItem(sliders[index])
    hlayouts[index].addWidget(spins[index])

    index += 1

vlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
for i in range(len(hlayouts)):
    vlayout.addLayout(hlayouts[i])
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just add set the layout on an empty QWidget and set the StyleSheet on this widget.

```
for index, param_name in enumerate(parameters):
    container = QtGui.QWidget(self)
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(container )

    hlayouts.append(container)
    labels.append(QtGui.QLabel("%s"%param_name))
    sliders.append(QtGui.QSpacerItem(10,10,hPolicy=QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
    spins.append(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox())

    spins[index].setValue(float(values.get(param_name)))
    container.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;")

    layout.addWidget(labels[index])
    layout.addItem(sliders[index])
    layout.addWidget(spins[index])


vlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
for widget in hlayouts:
    vlayout.addWidget(widget)
```

Comment: that does not set each layout of the loop, it sets the entire frame

Comment: you cant use .addWidget() on a widget, which is the container

Comment: And I don't. I use addWidget on the layout.

Comment: sorry didnt see some of the differences in your code